# A trigger for Adding a welcome message to the employee profile upon adding

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this sample database and I would like to add a welcome text into 2 columns after adding a new employee into the table of employees via trigger.

But it's gives me syntax error.

Here is my code snippet attempt:

```
DELIMITER$$
BEGIN
after insert into employeenumber for each row,
set action='update',
set sms='welcome',
set emails='welcome';
END
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: What is the error.  And why use a trigger, why not insert it with the regular data, or make those columns have a default value?

Comment: MYSQL said:#1064- You have an error in your SQL syntx; check    the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN' after insert into employeenumber for each row,set action='update', set at line 2

Comment: What about my other 2 questions?  If every row is going to have the same data after insert, why bother with a trigger?  Why not use defaults for the column, or insert the data with the insertion of the row?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your syntax.  Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `afterEmployeeNumberInsert` before INSERT ON employeenumber
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.action = 'update',
       NEW.sms = 'welcome',
       NEW.emails = 'welcome';
END
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fb81) working.

Now, having said that, I don't see why you need a trigger to insert the same data for every row that is inserted.  You are adding extra code when the database can perform the work for you.

Here is a link to the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
> row.
>
> ...
>
> A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have
> the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. You can refer to a column
> named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE
> trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value
> if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a
> trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to
> update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger
> because the row change will have already occurred.)

Comment: Thank you so much Dr.neel for your kind attention. but , I would like to say that I want to modify the same columns in the table employee via my trigger and add to the coming following columns of sms and emails the 'welcome' message via the trigger.

Comment: After insertion of a new row in the table of employees

Comment: You can't update the row that was inserted in an after trigger.
"Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger".  You have to use before.  If you look at the fiddle the result is the same